# AWS s3 forces 302 redirects when url has no trailing slash - need 301s

Tags: redirect, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-headers, http-redirect

I'm migrating a Wordpress site to a static site hosted in an Amazon s3 bucket. All pages are in a directory structure (eg, blog/index.html) but can be accessed via /blog/.

By default, Amazon redirects urls missing trailing slashes via a 302 redirect (www.site.com/page -- 302 --> www.site.com/page/). This is awful for SEO, and I'm trying to make these redirects 301s.

I've tried adding page.html objects in the root directory and setting up a redirect to /page/ per Amazon's instructions. This only creates 301s for /page.html. /page still causes a 302.

Amazon's redirect instructions: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html

Relevant blog post on issue: 
http://moz.com/community/q/new-static-site-with-302s

Has anyone encountered this, or have any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 11):

You can fix this problem now using CloudFront and Lambda@Edge. You can intercept the request coming back from S3 using the 'origin response' event and then change the response status-code to 301.

Below is the code you need to add to your Lambda handler.

```js
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const response = event.Records[0].cf.response;
    if (response.status === '302') {
        response.status = '301';
        response.statusDescription = 'Moved Permanently'
    }
    return response;
};
```

Here's a blog post, **I wrote**, that explains how to do this in detail

https://www.vividbytes.io/fixing-redirect-codes-on-static-s3-websites/

Comment: thanks, this helped. Even now I couldn't find a better solution. Tried using cloudfront function, they are very fast (max <1ms) but can't change response status :|

Comment: tried and test the response from the lambda and return 301 but when I hit the site, it return error that invalid json

Comment: This works and it should be  callback (null, response); This will send propper response

Answer (score 7):

According to the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/IndexDocumentSupport.html), it is indeed their design to return a 302:

> ... if you exclude the trailing slash from the preceding URL, Amazon S3 first looks for an object `photos` in the bucket. If the `photos` object is not found, then it searches for an index document, `photos/index.html`. If that document is found, Amazon S3 returns a `302 Found` message and points to the `photos/` key. For subsequent requests to `photos/`, Amazon S3 returns `photos/index.html`."

Going by the letter of their documentation, try renaming your `page.html` objects to simply be called `page` (without the .html extension).  It sucks that you have to do this for every URL containing a trailing slash, but we're stuck with it until Amazon lets us configure the actual redirect code for this behavior.